# z-index issue, image overlaping div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Somehow I can't see to make it work..

I'm trying to send the picture  to the back, this is just an example, I'm generating a graph on the fly with one of our BI programs, unfortunately the png that it generates is to big compared to the actual data, so I want to send the white remaining space to the back, however it overlaps the div border, I've been trying to prevent this with zindex property, but I can't get it done, some help will be highly appreciated, I'm open to any css or jquery solution.
The image on the fiddle is just an example of a picture overlaping the border.

http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/b3AXf/

Does anyone has an advice on how to send the picture to the back ?

Comment: You have just slammed all your code into the HTML pane of jsfiddle. To help people out in the future I suggest putting the CSS in the CSS pane, the HTML in the HTML pane, and the JavaScript in the JavaScript pane.

Comment: all right, sorry for the inconvenience I barely opened an account and I'm still learning how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `overflow:hidden;` to the `#utilitiesContainer`. That will solve the problem. [Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hu7Ad/), I hope that's what you ask for.

[Check here](http://www.ntutorials.com/css/prop_overflow), if you're interested more on the overflow property.

Comment: excelent! this solved the issue, would you mind explaining why it behaves like that?

Comment: Its because the child element is larger than the parent but CSS doesn't default overflowing content to be hidden. Hence having to set overflow:hidden; on the parent element.

Comment: Well, by default if the content does not fits to the container, it will continue to be displayed even outside the borders, as it was in your case. When you add an overflow:hidden to the container, it clips the content that goes outside the borders. You can also use overflow:hidden to adjust to the flow when you're using floating elements :)

Comment: thanks for that man, you solved in 1 min something that I've been breaking my head on for the last 3 hours, I'll mark this as accepted as soon as it lets me.